# Simple opening hours

Tags: ios, time

I am developing an application for a small restaurant, and would like to have a tab including the opening hours.

First of all i want to simply display the opening hours using labels, created by the interface builder. However, i would like to make a label and icon which programmatically are checking if the restaurant is currently open, according to the opening hours, and then display a icon and change the text of a label.

How do I get started?

Comment: Do you have some pseudo-code or an idea of how to do it? Have you looked at the docs for `NSDate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NSDate with setting the date format to hh:mm and compare it with your opening hours.

```
  NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger currentHour = [components hour];
NSInteger currentMinute = [components minute];
NSInteger currentSecond = [components second];

NSLog(@"%d",currentHour);
if (currentHour < 09 || (currentHour > 21 || (currentHour == 21 && (currentMinute > 0 || currentSecond > 0)))) {
    // Do Something
    NSLog(@"Open");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"not open");
}
```

Comment: Okay i get that - but how would you compare it? Should i create a sepereate strings containing the opening hours in HH:mm format and then If currentTime > timeMonday..... Then .... Or could you give me a hint? :)

Comment: Replace 09 with your opening hour and 21 with the closing hour time

Comment: good luck with `09` ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot ;) I know the digits should be without a zero :)